# How to Connect command prompt and Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, cmd

I am new to C# and I am creating a UI for iperf(windows).

Since I could not obtain the source code for the windows version, I have to try a different method.

My aim is to create a UI which will re-direct the commands to command prompt and get the output and display it back in Visual Studio.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You would be writing a program to launch the application and then redirect the output back to your program. Visual Studio is just the tool you use to write your program.

Comment: How can you show output back in Visual Studio..? Its an IDE.. Learn Visual Studio 2008 IDE.. go through link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165088%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "your command here";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Now `output` string variable holds result of command execution.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Comment: And what should I use to write commands in command prompt through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. It will allow you to start a new process and redirect the output and error streams.

EDIT:

After reading again it is not clear why you would want to redirect back to Visual Studio. I initially read this as you want to write a UI that will send commands and display the output using Visual Studio, not actually displaying in Visual Studio.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant displaying the result through visual studio and not actually displaying it in visual studio. 
I should have worded my question differently.